Hiding Manage Parent button in Sharepoint online
We would like to ask for advice of following customization:
In Sharepoint server 2019, we hid "Manage Parent" button (when modifying permission of site or list item) by inserting a custom script to
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\user.aspx
(doing directy in the server where Sharepoint server was installed).
The script:
<script type="text/javascript"> var error = document.getElementById("Ribbon.Permission.Parent.ManageParent-Large"); if(error) error.style.display = 'none'; </script>
How can we do similarly in Sharepoint 365 (online)?
Thanks in advance.

As per my knowledge, no , it is impossible to hide manage parent button in SharePoint.

Dear Allen,
Thanks for your reply. I think there should be a way to work with default page, similar way which we did with on-premise Sharepoint version.
